# Matrix Transpose ( List index out of range error )

Tags: python, transpose, indexoutofrangeexception

```
def transpose(A,size):
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(i,size):
        temp=A[i][j]
        A[i][j]=A[j][i]
        A[j][i]=temp
```

This is my transpose() function for a matrix but when I run it, the compiler throws an error saying list index out of range and I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the range from (i,size) to (size) will solve the out of range error

```
def transpose(A,size):
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            temp=A[i][j]
            A[i][j]=A[j][i]
            A[j][i]=temp
```

But The matrix A will not get modified because of referencing

It is better to use a new matrix for transpose

```
def transpose(A,size):
  B=list([0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size))
  for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
      B[i][j]=A[j][i]
            
  print(B)
```